# How to remove package that the os can't find?

Tags: 14.04, vmware

Please need you help , how can i remove all the VMware dependencies in mine case ?

I tried to install the  `'VMware Workstation Pro 14.0.0 build 6661328 for Linux'` but want to switch to VirtualBox ..

```
someone@someone-System-Product-Name:/usr/bin$ sudo find / -name vmware
/var/log/vmware
/var/lib/vmware
/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware
/etc/vmware
/etc/init.d/vmware
/etc/vmware-tools/scripts/vmware
/usr/bin/vmware
/usr/lib/vmware-ovftool/schemas/vmware
/usr/lib/vmware
/usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic/include/config/infiniband/vmware
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic/include/config/vmware
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic/include/config/infiniband/vmware
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic/include/config/vmware
/run/vmware

someone@someone-System-Product-Name:/usr/bin$ sudo apt-get autoremove vmware
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package vmware


someone@someone-System-Product-Name:/usr/bin$ sudo apt-get purge  vmware
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package vmware
```

Folder Structure :

```
someone@someone-System-Product-Name:~/Downloads/VMware Workstation Pro 14.0.0 build 6661328 for Linux$ ls -l
total 447800
-rw-rw-r-- 1 someone someone        29 Feb 14 15:32 serial.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 someone someone       119 Feb 14 15:32 sha256.sum
-rwxrwxr-x 1 someone someone 458534208 Feb 14 15:32 VMware-Workstation-Full-14.0.0-6661328.x86_64.bundle
```

Then i tried to run the long script to delete all and got this messages .

```
sudo rm -rf /var/log/vmware && 
sudo rm -rf /snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware &&
sudo rm -rf /etc/vmware &&
sudo rm -rf /etc/vmware-tools/scripts/vmware &&
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/vmware &&
sudo rm -rf /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic/include/config/infiniband/vmware &&
sudo rm -rf /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic/include/config/vmware &&
sudo rm -rf /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic/include/config/infiniband/vmware &&
sudo rm -rf /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic/include/config/vmware
```

Messages:

```
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/__init__.py': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-35.pyc': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/__init__.py': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-35.pyc': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/__pycache__/boot_proto.cpython-35.pyc': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/__pycache__/config.cpython-35.pyc': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/__pycache__/config_custom_script.cpython-35.pyc': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/__pycache__/config_file.cpython-35.pyc': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/__pycache__/config_namespace.cpython-35.pyc': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/__pycache__/config_nic.cpython-35.pyc': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/__pycache__/config_passwd.cpython-35.pyc': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/__pycache__/config_source.cpython-35.pyc': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/__pycache__/guestcust_error.cpython-35.pyc': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/__pycache__/guestcust_event.cpython-35.pyc': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/__pycache__/guestcust_state.cpython-35.pyc': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/__pycache__/guestcust_util.cpython-35.pyc': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/__pycache__/ipv4_mode.cpython-35.pyc': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/__pycache__/nic.cpython-35.pyc': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/__pycache__/nic_base.cpython-35.pyc': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/boot_proto.py': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/config.py': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/config_custom_script.py': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/config_file.py': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/config_namespace.py': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/config_nic.py': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/config_passwd.py': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/config_source.py': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/guestcust_error.py': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/guestcust_event.py': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/guestcust_state.py': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/guestcust_util.py': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/ipv4_mode.py': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/nic.py': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/vmware/imc/nic_base.py': Read-only file system


someone@someone-System-Product-Name:~$ dpkg -l snap
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  snap           <none>       <none>       (no description available)


someone@someone-System-Product-Name:~$ dpkg -l vmware
dpkg-query: no packages found matching vmware
someone@someone-System-Product-Name:~$ dpkg -l *vmware*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
```

Comment: How did you install `vmware`?

Comment: cd to mine folder with vmware , make it executable and run ..

Comment: Make what executable? Then it is not a package. Look in that folder for uninstallation instructions.

Comment: Sorry i will add some information about mine folder .

Comment: VMware-Workstation-Full-14.0.0-6661328.x86_64.bundle , the file that i executed

Comment: Try to run it with `--uninstall` at the end.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dpkg -l *vmware*` and `snap list`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: added to mine question

Answer (score 0):

According to [vmware](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.get_started.doc%2FGUID-05E4C876-F32C-49D2-82B4-8C759691E7F5.html) site uninstall should be done by

```
sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-workstation
```

Comment: It is very strange i run your command , and it seems like made me uninstall , then i checked again after reboot mine pc and got the same result after -> sudo find / -name vmware